# How TF is calculated?

Tags: r, tf-idf

Im really confused about how TF is calculated.
I understand that `TF = count of term x/ total # of terms`

For example:

```
Doc1: This is an example
Doc2: This is another example

TF(this,doc1)= 1/4= 0.25
```

However, some resources in R and links like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4858932/4458047), Consider `TF as count of term x`; for ex: `TF(this,doc1)= 1`  then multiply it by IDF.

Is that correct?

Comment: a look at the wikipedia article reveals that both are possible, with different ways to model the term frequency being available. The decision, which one to use, it depending on your application context https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf#Term_frequency_2

Comment: @Rickyfox , but is the recommended one to use is the TF which is the count of the term ?

Comment: that's what I was taught in my information retrieval class back then,yes.